# Is there any way to programmatically generate a CouchDB cookie?

Tags: authentication, couchdb

I'm working on an app which will use CouchDB to store some data for users.  But I don't want users to log into CouchDB directly.

I will have an app client (mobile/web), an app server, and the CouchDB server.  The client app will authenticate to the app server, then myy ideal scenario would be for my app server to authenticate the users programmatically, then send just the 10-minute cookie to the client app.

That is, I would like the app server to request a Cookie from the CouchDB server on behalf of the user of the app client, then send only the cookie to the app client.

The app server *could* just POST to _session on behalf of the authenticated user, but this requires:

1. maintaining a list of users' passwords in the app server
2. using a single, known, password for all users
3. resetting the password to something random for each authentication request

For security reasons, #3 seems the best, but this seems like extra work, and is an extra round-trip to the DB (albeit, not an expensive one).  So my question is:  Is there any, as an administrator, way to generate a cookie on behalf of a user, without using the users' password at all?

This would also potentially allow me to entirely reject requests to _session except from my app server, as an added security measure.

---

And for the sake of completeness, I'll also mention that I've looked at these other options, and found them wanting:

1. [Proxy Auth](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/authn.html#proxy-authentication)

   The fact that the [x_auth_token](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/auth.html#couch_httpd_auth/x_auth_token) never expires is worrisome to me. It means a compromised token would grant forever access to the user's data.  And AFAICT, the token can't even be invalidated without changing the user name or the server secret (which would in effect invalidate everyone else's auth tokens as well).  But maybe I'm missing something here?
2. [OAuth auth](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/authn.html#oauth-authentication)

   This seems to just move the problem. Now rather than storing users' passwords in my server app, I have to store OAuth secrets. Plus, now my server and client code must be more complicated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't follow your exact goals. You seem to imply users might have passwords ("app server authenticating the users programmatically") but you don't want the users to "ever need to know their CouchDB password". What sort of authentication do you want?

There's two (and a half) general approaches I've taken to authentication with CouchDB:

1. "Man-in-the-middle[ware]" approach, where I have thin middleware in front of CouchDB. This middleware forwards username/password to the "/_session" which yields a cookie or error codes based on the CouchDB _users database. The middleware copies this cookie from CouchDB onto its own HTTP response back to the client (or displays a message in case of error). Then on subsequent requests, that need database access, it forwards the cookie (now from the client request) back again to the database.
2. The traditional approach, where you just use CouchDB as a data store and maintain your own "user" entries/indexes. Make sure you use current best practices for password storage/handling or use a library that takes care of those details for you. The middleware connects to the database as "itself" and handles read/write permissions with its own logic based on its own session handling.
3. Or — sort of a hybrid approach — you can use the "/_session" API *only* to see if CouchDB accepts the username+password as valid. If it does, create a separate middleware-handled session for that user. (Basically you're only using CouchDB's _user database as the "password handling library" and the rest is the traditional approach where the access control is implemented all in the middleware rather than at the database.)

For real-world production stuff, I've tended to use only the latter two (or one-and-a-half given the earlier numbering…) — the first method is kind of fun, but CouchDB's lack of document-level read permissions usually means that giving users nearly-direct access to the database server is untenable in practice.

---

**UPDATE**: your question now makes it clear that you want the client app to talk directly to *both* servers: the app (formerly "middleware") server **and** the CouchDB (database) server. I'm leaving the content above because I think it's still somewhat useful and provides a bit of background/context for this update.

You are right in your suspicions that [Proxy Authentication](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/authn.html#proxy-authentication) is the wrong solution: it is *not* intended for end-user usage, but really to replace the cookie-forwarding "trick" portion of #1 above. That is, proxy authentication is when you fully trust *one* party (i.e. your *middle*ware) to provide the user information as it works *on behalf of* a user. But you want the users to talk to the database *directly*, and you cannot trust them with the `X-Auth-CouchDB-Token`.

I will defer to your judgement on the OAuth option. I do think it is closer to want you want but it is clear that somehow you are authenticating users against a different service and don't need to store [per-user keys in CouchDB](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/auth.html#http-oauth-configuration) itself. The request signing required by OAuth 1.0 does mean you'd need support in your client app's HTTP library too.

I see a few options, without building a custom CouchDB plugin, that could let your *app* server hand out a token to authenticated users which your *database* server will accept:

1. Proxy after all! That is, hide your database server behind your app server or another lightweight custom reverse-proxy. All this middleware needs to do is check your existing client app session (cookie or other authentication header) and if it's valid, set the internal [proxy auth headers](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/authn.html#proxy-authentication) that CouchDB will accept — then it forwards the rest of the request/response verbatim.
2. Deterministic password, per-user if it makes you feel better. Configure your app server with a secret known only to it, then set each user password to something like `HMAC(username, app_server_secret)`. Now when you want to generate a token for a user, your app server can generate the password on a per-user basis. Note that this really isn't any more secure than just using the `app_server_secret` as the password for every user — CouchDB already salts and hashes each user password independently so if someone gets a hold of the database but not your app's configuration values the attacker couldn't tell the two apart. In both cases, preventing unauthorized database usage hinges entirely on keeping `app_server_secret` secret.
3. Re-implement CouchDB's current cookie generation algorithm. CouchDB's cookie algorithm ([view source](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-couch/blob/f02f5f94a727fc2b2d080afae49c9392581090aa/src/couch_httpd_auth.erl#L266)) is basically `data = username + ':' + timestamp; base64(data + ':' + sha_mac(data, secret))`. Where `secret` is the `couch_httpd_auth.secret` value plus the user's `salt` value. You can tell your app server the [couchdb_httpd_auth/secret](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/auth.html#couch_httpd_auth/secret) value and it can follow the same steps to generate a valid cookie which you provide to the client app, and CouchDB will accept it as its own. This cookie will be valid until the timestamp + the configured couch_httpd_auth/timeout. As "hacky" as it seems, this is probably the closest to what you are asking for, although you still need to set/disable the users' actual passwords somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I apologize for asking an unclear question. I have edited it to hopefully be more clear.  I'm basically looking to do what you propose in #1, but hoping there's a way to avoid using the users' password entirely. That is, let an authenticated admin user generate a user's cookie without knowing their password, so that the password needn't be known at all.

Comment: #3 does indeed look like the closest to what I'm looking for. Thanks a ton for your in-depth answer, and coverage of all the various angles to approach the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [natevw's brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32292822/1677912). I was having similar problems, and never would have realized option 3 was possible without having stumbled across that answer.

Here is my python3 implementation for generating a cookie (uses pycouchdb to interface with couch):

```
def generate_couchdb_cookie(couchAddress, couchSecret, username):

    timestamp = format(int(time.time()), 'X')
    data      = username + ":" + timestamp

    server    = pycouchdb.Server(couchAddress)
    db        = server.database("_users")
    doc       = db.get("org.couchdb.user:" + username)
    salt      = doc["salt"]
    secret    = couchSecret + salt

    hashed    = hmac.new(secret.encode(), data.encode(), hashlib.sha1).digest()
    inbytes   = data.encode() + ":".encode() + hashed
    result    = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(inbytes)

    return "AuthSession=" + (result.decode("utf-8")).rstrip('=')
```