# How to check if user token is still valid in CouchDB?

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, couchdb

When you want to log in with a user you send a `POST` request to `http://localhost:5984/_session` and get back a cookie. This cookie is valid for 10 minutes by default and is stored in my `$_COOKIE` variable.

In my scenario I want the user to be able to interact with my website based upon the fact that he is logged in (eg. has a valid token) or not. My question is how can I check if a users cookie is still valid against my CouchDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32292822/13860):

> CouchDB's cookie algorithm (view source) is basically `data = username + ':' + timestamp; base64(data + ':' + sha_mac(data, secret))`. Where `secret` is the [couch_httpd_auth.secret](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/auth.html#couch_httpd_auth/secret) value plus the user's salt value.

This means that if all you want to do is check the timestamp, you can Base64 decode the cookie, then extract the timestamp from the result, and compare against the current time.

If you want to actually validate that the cookie is valid (i.e. not forged), you'll need to know the user's password salt, and the server secret. If this is a client-side app, that's dangerous. Even if it's a server app, it's putting that sensitive information in more places, which does come with additional security risks. Whether those risks are worth it is up to you, and your implementation.

Comment: Great advice but I think it's not what I should implement because of the downsides you mentioned. Would you personally use this method when you want to run server-side actions (eg. functions) only in the context of a user who is logged in?

Comment: @Magiranu: I would probably just check the token with the CouchDB server (`GET /_session`), to let CouchDB validate it.  If that introduces performance concerns, you can cache it on the server.  I'd do the lookup the first time, then cache the timestamp and the full cookie; then you don't need to re-validate the cookie for each request, and can still trust the timestamp (since the full token was previously validated)

Comment: With "check token" you mean to send within the GET request the cookie via the header? (Souce: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/server/authn.html#get--_session)

Comment: @Magiranu Yes, exactly.