# CouchDB Proxy Authentication security - user roles confusion

Tags: authentication, couchdb

On user auth success my auth server generates a token and passes it to the client.

The docs say that the client has to add the following headers:

> X-Auth-CouchDB-UserName: username;
>   **X-Auth-CouchDB-Roles**:comma-separated (,) list of user roles;
>   X-Auth-CouchDB-Token: authentication token.

**Does it mean that the client defines his own roles on every request? Why can't he add 'admin' into the list of roles then?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A client is anything that uses or requests resources from a server.

"The client" in this case is your proxy/auth server, not a web browser.  (The documentation could probably stand to be clarified a bit.)

So yes, your proxy/auth server, the client to CouchDB, should set that header as appropriate.

By extension, it should also *not* pass through any `X-Auth-Couch` headers received from *its* client (presumably a web browser).

Comment: Hi Flimzy and thanks for the clarifying answer. I'm still not quite sure, whether it is possible to use Proxy Authentication mechanism with a 3rd party authentication/user db.

I thought, that after I authenticate the user on my server, the server can, in its turn, send a proxy auth request to the couchdb as well as supply the user (web browser) with a generated token in order for him to speak to couchdb.  But in case if the user can later alter the Roles header, the mechanism turns out useless. Or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: One option would be to forward all request from the user (pouchdb) via the proxy-server which would simply add appropriate headers.. which is not very performant I suppose

Comment: If you want your auth server to facilitate an auth token to a client, just have it send a standard CouchDB cookie. You can have your auth server create the session with CouchDB, then forward the cookie to the web browser (along with proper CORS configuration).  Alternately, you can have your auth server create a validCouchDB cookie [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32292183/13860).

Comment: Or as you surmise, you can just proxy all requests. Whether that is performat or not depends on implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link, for now I'll try to stick to the proxy middleware approach

Comment: The proxy approach is what I chose in my most recent application, too. It's simpler in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Good observation. Using the [JWT Authentication](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.1.1/api/server/authn.html#jwt-authentication) would seem to close this loophole as my understanding is the entire token is signed-over.

That said, in neither case can one avoid:

- having to fully trust the entity holding the secret
- having to carefully guard against leakage of its headers

The former is sort of unavoidable, as the point of these plugins is to delegate authentication. Either you trust the proxy (or JWT issuer) or you leave those `authentication_handlers` disabled.

The latter is something that e.g. [OAuth 1](https://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Signing.html) hardened itself somewhat against, in that ± the entire request was signed over and one couldn't simply take a couple auth headers from an earlier leaked request and slap them on a new forged request. Nonce and timestamp fields were supposed to be checked to avoid verbatim replays of prior requests as well. (All this was dropped in [OAuth 2](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/127#issuecomment-7492967) for whatever that's worth… and even OAuth 1 had some [notable loopholes](https://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth1/security.html) in practice…)

So in practice either the Proxy or the JWT authentication handlers should be used with care. Assuming a "firewall" of sorts drawn around both your CouchDB and authentication source, then as @Flimzy's answer mentions preventing unexpected headers making their way inwards from outside that boundary — as well as keeping the real headers from leaking outwards — should mitigate most potential abuse.